# Conditionally remove sections of XML document with Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How would i using Linq remove all `<CCInfo>` section where their element `<CC>` does not have the value 0123 ?

Source document:

```
<Processing>
  <Mods>
    <ListMods>
      <Action>A</Action>
      <GetMoreInd></GetMoreInd>
      <QLDNameReq></QLDNameReq>
      <CCAry>
        <CCInfo>
          <CC>0123</CC>
          <Num>25</Num>
          <Cat></Cat>
          <DtRange></DtRange>
        </CCInfo>
        <CCInfo>
            <CC>456</CC>
            <Num>25</Num>
            <Cat></Cat>
            <DtRange></DtRange>
          </CCInfo>
          <CCInfo>
            <CC>0123</CC>
            <Num>99</Num>
            <Cat></Cat>
            <DtRange></DtRange>
          </CCInfo>
          <CCInfo>
            <CC>0123</CC>
            <Num>16</Num>
            <Cat></Cat>
            <DtRange></DtRange>
          </CCInfo>
          <CCInfo>
            <CC>xyz</CC>
            <Num>16</Num>
            <Cat></Cat>
            <DtRange></DtRange>
          </CCInfo>
        </CCAry>
      </ListMods>
  </Mods>
</Processing>
```

Wanted output

```
<Processing>
  <Mods>
    <ListMods>
      <Action>A</Action>
      <GetMoreInd></GetMoreInd>
      <QLDNameReq></QLDNameReq>
      <CCAry>
        <CCInfo>
          <CC>0123</CC>
          <Num>25</Num>
          <Cat></Cat>
          <DtRange></DtRange>
        </CCInfo>
          <CCInfo>
            <CC>0123</CC>
            <Num>99</Num>
            <Cat></Cat>
            <DtRange></DtRange>
          </CCInfo>
          <CCInfo>
            <CC>0123</CC>
            <Num>16</Num>
            <Cat></Cat>
            <DtRange></DtRange>
          </CCInfo>
        </CCAry>
      </ListMods>
  </Mods>
</Processing>
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query for the `CCInfo` nodes, compare the `CC` element's value against your desired value, then call the [`XNode.Remove method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx):

```
var query = xml.Descendants("CCInfo")
               .Where(e => e.Element("CC").Value != "0123");
query.Remove();
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Comment: Wow thank you I thought i would need to remove each section in turn! thanks for the quick answer...